# Find link path a directory up from your current link (javascript)

Tags: javascript, menu

I have a bit of javascript that finds a link on the page and if it's the same link as the current page it changes the css to current. This works fine. But what I want to do is extend this so for instance lets same the link is mysite.com/blog/post. I want it to go up a directory i.e. mysite.com/blog find if that links on the page and if it is highlight it, hopefully that makes sense.The code I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
var path = location.pathname;
if ( path )
 $('#sidebar ul.archive a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'current');
 }); 
</script>
```

So I'm thinking I just need to change the var path to find the link to the directory above, but can't figure out how I'd do that?

Comment: If path is `/a/b/c/`, then `/a/b/c/../` is the parent directory. it's not pretty, but it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try parsing the `location.pathname` to remove the rightmost directory. Eg:

```
var path = location.pathname;
var parentPath = path.substr(0,path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: thanks, sounds like what I'm after but it selects the current link rather then the link to the directory above

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly..

```
$('#sidebar ul.archive a').filter(function() {
    return path.match($(this).attr('href'));
}).addClass('current');
```

For example, this will add class `current` to the link `<a href="/blog">Blog</a>` if the current page is `mysite.com/blog/post`.